# Dynamically Creating, Naming, and Placing Queues

Tags: c++, dynamic, struct, queue

I have a program in which a user enters in the number of queues that they want.  Is it possible for my program to somehow then take that number and dynamically create queues (names and all).  Also, once the queues are created, I would like to be able to loop through them, so I want to put them in an array called **arrayOfQueues**.  The last thing to note is that the queues hold a struct called **Process**.

The following code might help set up my scenario better than I can type it:

**UPDATED:**

```
void function(int numQueues){
vector<queue<Process>> vectorOfQueues;
for(int i=0; i<numQueues; i++){
    vectorOfQueues.push_back(queue<Process>());
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::queue<Process>>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB That is a good suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your concern is only to create an iteratable collection of queues, do as [Kerrek suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280069/dynamically-creating-naming-and-placing-queues#comment18104418_13280069) and use a `vector` of queues. But you say you want to name them. In that case you may want to keep them in an `std::unordered_map<std::string,std::queue<Process>>` in order to access them through their name.

Regarding your update, it's much too complicated. The same can be achieved easier:

```
std::vector<std::queue<Process>> vectorOfQueues(numQueues,std::queue<Process>{});
```

or

```
std::vector<std::queue<Process>> vectorOfQueues;
vectorOfQueues.resize(numQueues);
```

is sufficient.

Comment: Does my edited code more accurately reflect what you are getting at?

Comment: @Rick_Sch: See my edit. You can directly create the queue with the appropriate size. You could also use the `std::vector::resize` member function to change the size of the vector and have all queues default constructed (to empty queues).